# Meteor - Can't submit user after adding routes with iron.Router to the login and register form

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, iron-router, spacebars

I want to create a simple Login, Register and Logout menu with [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/) and [Iron Router](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router). Before I used the Iron Router package I could submit a new user and easily login or logout. Therefore I had this code in my html document:

```
<body>
  {{#if currentUser}}
    {{> dashboard}}
  {{else}}
    {{> register}}<br>
    {{> login}}
  {{/if}}
</body>
```

Now I want to route the login and register form. If you press the Login button we should get: *lochalhost:3000* login (which works fine).

**But** I don't know:

- why I can't submit a new user anymore
- how I can change from the successful login route to the dashboard route
- and probably how I can logout (couldn't test it yet)

I'm new to JS and Meteor. Still I didn't find a solution in the Internet or a way to fix it on my own.

My complete document looks like:

- **main.html:**

  ```
  <head>
    <title>Routing</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    {{#if currentUser}}
      {{> dashboard}}
    <!--{{else}}
      {{> register}}<br>
      {{> login}} -->
    {{/if}}
  </body>

  <template name="main">
      <h1>Text</h1>
      {{> navigation}}
      {{> yield}}
      <hr />
      <p>
        Copyright &copy;
      </p>
  </template>

  <template name="home">
    <p>
      Welcome to the <b>Text</b> website.
    </p>
  </template>

  <template name="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="{{pathFor route='home'}}">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="{{pathFor route='register'}}">Register</a></li>
      <li><a href="{{pathFor route='login'}}">Login</a></li>
    </ul>
  </template>

  <template name="register">
    <form>
      <input type="text" id="username">
      <input type="text" id="email">
      <input type="password" id="password">
      <input type="submit" value="Register">
    </form>
  </template>

  <template name="login">
    <form>
      <input type="text" id="login-email">
      <input type="password" id="login-password">
      <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>
  </template>

  <template name="dashboard">
    <p>
      Yor're logged in.
      <a href="{{pathFor route='home'}}" class="logout">Logout</a>
    </p>
  </template>
  ```
- **main.js**

  ```
    Router.route('register'); // Default name is register
    Router.route('login'); // Default name is login
    Router.route('dashboard');
    Router.route('/', {
      name: 'home',
      template: 'home'
    });

    Router.configure({
      layoutTemplate: 'main'
    });


    if (Meteor.isClient) {
      Template.register.events({
        'submit form': function(event, template) {
          event.preventDefault();
          var usernameVar = template.find('#username').value;
          var emailVar = template.find('#email').value;
          var passwordVar = template.find('#password').value;
          Accounts.createUser({
            username: usernameVar,
            email: emailVar,
            password: passwordVar
          })
        }
      });

  Template.login.events({
    'submit form': function(event, template) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var emailVar = template.find('#login-email').value;
      var passwordVar = template.find('#login-password').value;
      Meteor.loginWithPassword(emailVar, passwordVar);
    }
  });
  Template.dashboard.events({
    'click .logout': function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      Meteor.logout();
      prompt("You successfully logged out");
    }
  });
  ```

  }

And I added:

- the `iron:router` package
- `meteor add accounts-ui accounts-password`

Answer (score 0):

I would say, do read the official documentation for Iron Router and Meteor to have better understanding. I took your code and did some testing, it works fine. I only added iron:router accounts-ui (Look up documentation for this, you can create easy login and signup with this package) and accounts-password.

**main.html**

```
<head>
   <title>Routing</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{#if currentUser}}
    {{> dashboard}}
  <!--{{else}}
    {{> register}}<br>
    {{> login}} -->
  {{/if}}
</body>

<template name="main">
    <h1>Text</h1>
    {{> navigation}}
    {{> yield}}
    <hr />
    <p>
      Copyright &copy;
    </p>
</template>

<template name="home">
  <p>
    Welcome to the <b>Text</b> website.
  </p>
</template>

<template name="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="{{pathFor route='home'}}">Home</a></li>
    {{#unless currentUser}}
    <li><a href="{{pathFor route='register'}}">Register</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{pathFor route='login'}}">Login</a></li>
    {{/unless}}
  </ul>
</template>

<template name="register">
  {{#unless currentUser}}
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="username">
    <input type="text" id="email">
    <input type="password" id="password">
    <input type="submit" value="Register">
  </form>
  {{/unless}}
</template>

<template name="login">
  {{#unless currentUser}}
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="login-email">
    <input type="password" id="login-password">
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
  </form>
  {{/unless}}
</template>

<template name="dashboard">
  <p>
    Yor're logged in.
    <a href="{{pathFor route='home'}}" class="logout">Logout</a>
  </p>
</template>
```

**main.js**

```
goHome =function(){
  if(Meteor.userId()){
    Router.go('/');
  }
}


Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'main'
});


Router.route('/register', {
  template:'register',
  onBeforeAction:function(){
    goHome();
    this.next();
  }
}); // Default name is register

Router.route('/login', {
  template:'login',
  onBeforeAction:function(){
    goHome();
    this.next();
  }
});

Router.route('/dashboard',{
  template:'dashboard'
})

Router.route('/', {
  name: 'home',
  template: 'home'
});


if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.register.events({
    'submit form': function(event, template) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var usernameVar = template.find('#username').value;
      var emailVar = template.find('#email').value;
      var passwordVar = template.find('#password').value;
      Accounts.createUser({
        username: usernameVar,
        email: emailVar,
        password: passwordVar
      }, function(error){
        if(!error){
          Router.go('/');
        }
      })
    }
  });

Template.login.events({
'submit form': function(event, template) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var emailVar = template.find('#login-email').value;
  var passwordVar = template.find('#login-password').value;
  Meteor.loginWithPassword(emailVar, passwordVar, function(error){
    if(!error){
      Router.go('/');
    }
  });
}
});
Template.dashboard.events({
'click .logout': function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  Meteor.logout();
  prompt("You successfully logged out");
}
});
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. Did you add "meteor add useraccounts:iron-routing" or what do you mean with " iron:router accounts-ui"? Your version doesn't work after copy pasting... I still got the same Problem.

Comment: i just added like so:
meteor add iron:router
meteor add accounts-password 

I only included accounts-ui to provide more information on easy sign up and login. It works without accounts-ui, however, with this package, you can create a login and signup easily just by calling {{> loginButtons}}.

Comment: Okay thanks :) Another way is to add Router.go("path");